# how to configure whmcs smarty template plugin?

Tags: php, smarty, whmcs

I have added the `function.bnr_exchange.php` to the `includes/smarty/plugins` directory. It contains `smarty_function_bnr_exchange` which returns a string.

I also modified invoicepdf.tpl

```
$pdf->Cell(0,6,{bnr_exchange} . '',0,1,'L','1');
```

which gives error:

> unexpected {

I tried with `"{bnr_exchange}"` but then it writes the text

> {bnr_exchange}

If I simply write `{bnr_exchange}` in the template it says

> unexpected }

in that line.

So it doesn't recognize the plugin "bnr_exchange".

My question is how do I tell whmcs that I have a file there with that plugin so it can see it?

Comment: Smarty syntax is annoying. Are you wrapping the whole statement in braces?

Comment: No. I just tried that and it gives { unexpected.

Comment: well - $pdf, in this case, must be $smarty->assign(k,v) in the php counterpart. Just be sure that its getting defined properly. You may need to post more code to get any good feedback here.

Comment: $pdf is working fine. I just want it to output something on the resulting pdf. The output itself works it's the plugin that doesn't work. Normally the plugin must be smarty->registerPlugin or something and I see a lot of generic code in whmcs which loads plugins and assigns variables but nothing that specifies which are the modules files. I would post more code from the assigned php file but that code is encrypted so I don't have it